# medium-editor custom binding

Tags: knockout.js, custom-binding, bindinghandlers, medium-editor

```
ko.bindingHandlers.editor = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {

            var initialValue = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor);
            var options = allBindingsAccessor().editoroptions || {};
            var editorElement = '#' + $(element).attr('id');

            $(editorElement).html(initialValue);

            ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "keyup", function () {
                var newvalue = $(editorElement).html().toString()
                valueAccessor(newvalue);
            });

            $(editorElement).on('input', function () {
                $(element).trigger("keyup");
            });

            var editor = new MediumEditor(editorElement, {
                buttons: ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'quote', 'anchor', 'superscript', 'subscript', 'orderedlist', 'unorderedlist', 'pre', 'outdent', 'indent'],
                buttonLabels: 'fontawesome',
                placeholder: options.initialText
            });

            ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
                editor.deactivate();
            });
        }
    };
```

[medium-editor.js](https://github.com/daviferreira/medium-editor)

this is how i declared my custom binding, but the problem is then underling observable gets updated when i type in editor. here is how i use it in markup.

```
    <div class="editor" id="ruleseditor" data-bind="editor: RuleText(), editoroptions:{initialText: 'No rules defined please enter new rules for application'}"></div>
```

and here is my VM bounded to my html.

```
define(["require", "exports", 'knockout'], function(require, exports, ko) {
var rules = (function () {
    function rules() {
        var _this = this;
        this.IsLoading = ko.observable();
        this.RuleText = ko.observable("thet with some optiona markup <h3> displayd in cool editor<?h3>");
        this.RuleText.subscribe(function (newvalue) {
            console.log("new value for rule ....... ", newvalue);
        });
        this.RuleOriginal = ko.computed(function () {
            return _this.RuleText();
        });
        this.activate = this._activateCallback;
    }
    rules.prototype._activateCallback = function () {
        this._getAppRules();
    };

    rules.prototype._getAppRules = function () {
    };
    return rules;
})();

return rules;
});
```

initial custom binding works as expected because I can see editor script activated and value gets passed to the editor my problem is that i can not update my observable after updating my html in editor.

Comment: Do you use another plugin for knockout? What's `ko.observable.update`? This is supposed to be `yourObservable(newValue)` instead, isn't it?

Comment: sorry i updated mu example still same problem can not update observable

Comment: Do you get an error? Do you enter this event?

Comment: yes i enter event not errors nothing changed i even used contenteditable bu this does not work in IE

Comment: remove parenthesis at `editor: RuleText()` => `editor: RuleText`

Comment: no that does not help I managed to make it work in all browsers but IE is problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you access valueAccessor is wrong, it is not what you think. Please read about valueAccessor in http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html

Try:

(1) change your binding from `editor: RuleText()` to `editor: RuleText` as `RuleText` is **the observable** you want, not the underneath value.

(2) fix your binding Handler

```
ko.bindingHandlers.editor = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {

        // you have to call valueAccessor() to get back the observable you passed in your binding.
        var value = valueAccessor(); 
        var options = allBindingsAccessor().editoroptions || {};
        var editorElement = '#' + $(element).attr('id');

        // unwrap observable value
        $(editorElement).html(ko.unwrap(value)); 

        ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "keyup", function () {
            var newvalue = $(editorElement).html().toString();

            // 'value' (not valueAccessor) is the observable you passed in.
            value(newvalue);
        });

        $(editorElement).on('input', function () {
            $(element).trigger("keyup");
        });

        var editor = new MediumEditor(editorElement, {
            buttons: ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'quote', 'anchor', 'superscript', 'subscript', 'orderedlist', 'unorderedlist', 'pre', 'outdent', 'indent'],
            buttonLabels: 'fontawesome',
            placeholder: options.initialText
        });

        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
            editor.deactivate();
        });
    }
};
```